# Forcing SSL on websockets and Tomcat With Spring using Safari bug

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, safari

We have an app using websockets with Spring on Tomcat 8.5

We are seeing problems using this combination of things

- Forcing SSL connection in tomcat using `<security-constraint>` in context.xml
- Using spring 4.2.6+
- browsing from Safari.

The problem we're running into is this one.

[WebSocket - Safari 9 - Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679134/websocket-safari-9-invalid-utf-8-sequence-in-header-value)

Essentially Safari is getting an empty Expires header sent to it.  The reason why it is empty is due to SPR-14053 which introduced resetting the Expires Header when caching is configured.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18625

What is happening is that in Tomcat when using  and not disabledProxyCaching, Tomcat sets and Expires Header

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#L508

I believe because the Header was previously set by Tomcat, instead of removing the Expire header from the response, it's simply set to blank, which causes the problems in safari.

I know i can workaround this, my question is, where should the fix for this lie?  Should this be filed against Safari, Spring or Tomcat's bug list?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I just realized, outside of Safari fixing their behavior on empty header. It may be just best to add the following to context.xml

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SSLAuthenticator" disableProxyCaching="false"/>`

and allow Spring to set the caching properties as normal.   Instead of having both Tomcat and Spring fight about which caching Headers to use.